# C# : how to use string in random?

Tags: c#, random

I am having a problem in C# programming, so I want to make a program that let the user enter names then do these following:

1. by clicking one button it should shows one name of these names by random
2. and other button should display all the names but make spaces between each 2 names (like grouping or something like that).

Thank you

Comment: Are you stuck on inputting the names? Handling a button click? Selecting something randomly? Displaying results? Do you have some code you have started on that doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you've collected the names into an array called "names", do the following to choose one at random.

```
Random rand = new Random();//Make a new instance of the "Random" class.
string randomname = names[rand.Next(names.Length)];//Sets "randomname" to the name value with a given index, this index is a random number between 0 and the length of the array.
```

And to gather all the names into one string with a name in between, use the following:

```
string output = "";//Initialise a variable for all the names to exist inside.
for(int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)//For every value in "names"
{
    output += names[i];//"output" has the newest value of "names" added onto the end.
    if (i < names.Length - 1)//If the name isn't the last one.
    {
        output+= " ";//Add the space.
    }
}
```

If there's any intermediate steps you need, just ask :p

Here's a modified version of your code.

```
 string[] myNames = new string[25]; //declare it globally 
 int index = 0; //declare it globally 
 string name = ""; // globally 
 private void findButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
 { 
     Random rand = new Random();//Make a new instance of the "Random" class. 
     string randomname = myNames[rand.Next(myNames.Length)]; 
 } 
 private void listGroupButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
 {
        //list group 
 }
 private void listGroupButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
 { //list group 
     string output = "";//Initialise a variable for all the names to exist inside. 
     for(int i = 0; i < myNames.Length; i++)//For every value in "names" 
     { 
         output += myNames[i];//"output" has the newest value of "names" added onto the end. 
         if (i < myNames.Length - 1)//If the name isn't the last one. 
         {
             output+= " ";//Add the space. 
         } 
     } 
     MessageBox.Show(output);
 }
```

Comment: thank you!! , but what shall i put to show the result in a message?                         the output ? MessageBox.Show(" "+ output);    because it didnt work ='(

Comment: What error did it give?

Comment: If you posted your code in the question that would help.

Comment: string[] myNames = new string[25]; //declare it globally
        int index = 0; //declare it globally
        string name = ""; // globally
private void findButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //random

Random rand = new Random();//Make a new instance of the "Random" class.
string randomname = names[rand.Next(names.Length)];



        }

Comment: private void listGroupButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //list group
string output = "";//Initialise a variable for all the names to exist inside.
for(int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)//For every value in "names"
{
    output += names[i];//"output" has the newest value of "names" added onto the end.
    if (i < names.Length - 1)//If the name isn't the last one.
    {
        output+= " ";//Add the space.
    }
}
        }

Comment: You haven't changed "names" to "myNames". I just used "names" as an example name for the array. Anywhere in my code where it says "names" use your array: "myNames".

Comment: yeah I have fixed it now but shouldnt I put a message box or something to show the result??

Comment: Sure, seeing as I answered the question, can you press the accept button on the answer please?

Comment: You're welcome, what're you trying to make anyway?

Comment: project for the collage that has a lot of buttons, but couldnt solve these two  =')

Comment: How long have you been learning C#?

Comment: i started  learning c# this year only, but i took java classes 3 years ago

Comment: What course are you taking?

Comment: Oh, I thought it would be something more general is all